# Отправка данных из таблицы sqlite телеграм ботом при появлении этих новых данных

Tags: python, база-данных, telegram-bot, sqlite, aiogram

Есть таблица с данными логин/пароль, туда они приходят после регистрации юзера. Нужно сделать так, чтобы как только эти данные записались в бд, они отправились сообщением от ТГ бота, то есть юзер зарегистрировался, данные записались в таблицу и оттуда они взялись и отправились сообщением в ТГ. Можно ли это осуществить через aiogram? А вообще подойдет любая другая библиотека. Буду очень благодарен, ибо даже представления не имею, как описать скриптом это событие, даже с чего начать. Код пишется на питоне.

Comment: а регистрация где происходит? на сайте, в приложении или тоже через телеграм-бота?

Answer (score 0):

Если в базу данных данные заносит ваш бот, то в том же хэндлере пропишите сразу отпраку этих же данных себе (ваш чат с ботом).
Т е одним хэндлером получаете данные, следующей строкой заносите их в базу данных и следующей строкой отправляете их себе.
Это логическая цепочка действий. Синтаксис зависит от того, каким вы способом собираете у пользователя данные, какую БД используете и как у вас это все реализовано в целом.